# how can I solve this ERROR: Expected singleton candidat(1,2,3,4)

Tags: python, odoo

```
def _get_index_content(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, args, context=None):
    res = dict.fromkeys(ids, '')
    Attachment = self.pool.get('ir.attachment')
    applicant_ids = self.pool.get('hr.applicant').search(cr, uid, [('email_from', '=', self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context).email_candidat)], context=context)
    attachment_ids = Attachment.search(cr, uid, ['|', '&', ('res_model', '=', 'candidat.base'), ('res_id', 'in', ids), '&', ('res_model', '=', 'hr.applicant'), ('res_id', 'in', applicant_ids)], context=context)
    for attachment in Attachment.browse(cr, uid, attachment_ids, context=context):
        res[attachment.res_id] += attachment.index_content or ''
    return res                  


def _content_search(self, cr, user, obj, name, args, context=None):
    record_ids = set()
    Attachment = self.pool.get('ir.attachment')
    ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [])
    applicant_ids = self.pool.get('hr.applicant').search(cr, user, [('email_from', '=', self.browse(cr, user, ids, context=context).email_candidat)], context=context)
    args = ['&'] + args + ['|', '&', ('res_model', '=', 'candidat.base'), ('res_id', 'in', ids), '&', ('res_model', '=', 'hr.applicant'), ('res_id', 'in', applicant_ids)]
    att_ids = Attachment.search(cr, user, args, context=context)
    record_ids = set(att.res_id for att in Attachment.browse(cr, user, att_ids, context=context))
    return [('id', 'in', list(record_ids))]
```

'index_content': fields.function(_get_index_content,fnct_search=_content_search, string='Index Content', type="text"),

I got Expected singleton candidat.base(1,2,3,4) as an ERROR.

Comment: are your receiving more than one result ?

Comment: yes it's possible that I receive more than one result

Comment: from https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/4377
it says "_the behaviour was changed to not allow reading from recordsets with multiple records._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
applicant_ids = self.pool.get('hr.applicant').search(cr, user, [('email_from', '=', self.browse(cr, user, ids, context=context).email_candidat)], context=context)
```

won't work if ids is a list of 2 or more IDs. The browse will get a RecordSet of 2 entries, on which you can't call for field values like `email_candidat`.

Try to search for all email addresses like:

```py
applicant_ids = self.pool.get('hr.applicant').search(cr, user, [('email_from', 'in', [x.email_candidat for x in self.browse(cr, user, ids, context=context)])], context=context)
```

And perhaps use some more lines to make that code more readable.